# Fast way to find strings in set of strings containing substring

Tags: string, algorithm, indexing, substring

## Task

I have a set *S* of *n* = 10,000,000 strings *s* and need to find the set *S*<sub>*p*</sub> containing the strings *s* of *S* that contain the substring *p*.

## Simple solution

As I'm using C# this is quite a simple task using LINQ:

```
string[] S = new string[] { "Hello", "world" };
string p = "ll";
IEnumerable<string> S_p = S.Where(s => s.Contains(p));
```

## Problem

If *S* contains many strings (like the mentioned 10,000,000 strings) this gets horribly slow.

## Idea

Build some kind of index to retrieve *S*<sub>*p*</sub> faster.

## Question

What is the best way to index *S* for this task and do you have any implementation in C#?

Comment: Is your set S constant? How many different p are used with the same S?

Comment: Yes, _S_ is constant. I will use thousands of different _p_ for _S_. It's a search-engine but the content won't change.

Comment: Have you considered lucene.net?

Comment: No I haven't yet. But from the first look it doesn't seem to be what I want. I'd like to have a lightweight solution with as less external dependencies as possible. The best would be a single, small C#-class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to do it:
1. Create a string `T = S[0] + sep_0 + S[1] + sep_1 + ... + S[n - 1] + sep_n-1`(where `sep_i` is a unique character that never appears in `S[j]` for any `j`(it can actually be an integer number if the set of characters is not big enough)).
2. Build a suffix tree for `T`(it can be done in linear time).
3. For each query string `Q` traverse the suffix tree(it takes `O(length(Q))` time). Then all possible answers will be located in the leaves of some subtree. So you can just traverse all these leaves. If `Q` is rather long, then the number of leaves in this subtree is likely to be much smaller than `n`.
4. If `Q` is really short, then the number of leaves in a subtree can be pretty large. That's why you can use another strategy for short query strings: precompute all short substrings of `S[0] ... S[n - 1]` and for each of them store a set of indices where it has occurred. Then you can just print these indices for a given `Q`. It is difficult to say what 'short' exactly means here, but it can be found out experimentally.

Comment: I read a bit about suffix trees and it seems that nowadays it's recommended to use _suffix arrays_ instead. Is there anything I oversaw or do you agree?

Comment: @user2033412 Finding the range of occurrenses for a query string can be done in O(length(Q) * log n) in a suffix array(not linear as in a suffix tree)unless you use hashing to compare strings, but in general suffix array is a good choice here too.

Comment: Can sep_i = sep_j for all _i_, _j_ or do I need different ones?

Comment: @user2033412 For a suffix tree they definitely should be different, for  a suffix array using the same separator for all `i` looks fine.

Comment: Am I right that the suffix array will return me a list containing the _positions_ of each occurrence of _p_ in _T_?

Comment: The easiest way to retrieve the strings _s_ would be to scan forwards and backwards from each position to the next separator, right? Is there a faster way to do that?

Comment: @user2033412 If storing one more array is not an issue, you can just precompute it in linear time when your build `T`. Then a string can be retrieved in `O(1)`.

Comment: What would I store? Example: _T_ = "$Hello$world$", _p_ = "o" would give me [5, 8]. How would I look this up in the additional array?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62837/discussion-between-user2033412-and-user2040251).

Comment: If I'm using the additional lookup-array I don't need a separator-character anymore, right?

Comment: @user2033412 You still need it. For example, if you concatenate `aa` and `bb` without a separator,  you will get `aabb` and eventually find `ab` there, even though it is not a substring of any of them.